# What's better to optimize a database: use a bunch of stored procedures with different filters or use a single one with if conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize my database so, I decided to change a stored procedure which has a lot of "IF CONDITIONS" to filter with different parameters.

So, I was thinking on change it and make a bunch of stored procedures with different filters and stop using the one with a lot of "IF CONDITIONS"

And just validate on my backend which stored procedure use, instead of do it in SQL Server.

This is the best way to do it or there are better ways to do this?

Example of my actual stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetFilters]
    @Id INT,
    @Name VARCHAR(50),
    @LastName VARCHAR(50),
    @Age INT,
    @AND_MORE_PARAMETERS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @ID IS NOT NULL AND 
       @NAME IS NULL AND 
       @LASTNAME IS NULL AND 
       @AGE IS NULL AND 
       @AND_MORE_PARAMETERS IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE 
        WHERE ID = @ID
    END
    ELSE IF @ID IS NULL AND 
            @NAME IS NOT NULL AND 
            @LASTNAME IS NULL AND 
            @AGE IS NULL AND 
            @AND_MORE_PARAMETERS IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE WHERE 
        NAME = @NAME
    END 
...
```

and so on..

I want to change that one to a bunch of different stored procedures, each one of them with a unique filter

It is a good idea? There are better ways to optimize this stored procedure?

Thanks, for the help!

Comment: Separate procedures will perform better but are harder to maintain (although lots of `if/else` is also hard to maintain). You may want to look at articles about [Kitchen Sink Queries](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example), research *safe* dynamic SQL and the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint

Comment: In your specific example I would suspect you will find the best compromise will be to separate the if/else logic from your actual queries. Move each select query to its own procedure and just pass the correct parameters; this will ensure each query gets its own dedicated cached execution plan and it can be recompiled in isolation.

Comment: Do not poke a sleeping bear. If you change it, you own it and you are responsible for anything that change causes. If you are not solving a problem, find something else to do. No one should be changing working code, no matter how beneficial it might appear to be.

Comment: @Stu execution plans are cached at the statement (plus @@options) level, so each select statement in the given example would have a separate plan. That said you can easily `sp_recompile N'someStoredProcedure'`, while it's more difficult to expunge a single statement's plan, so there is merit to using separate stored procedures as you suggest.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You could try one query, with parameter evaluation in the WHERE clause. I've used this approach widely with great success.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_GetFilters
    @Id                   INT         = NULL
    ,@Name                VARCHAR(50) = NULL
    ,@LastName            VARCHAR(50) = NULL
    ,@Age                 INT         = NULL
    ,@AND_MORE_PARAMETERS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT  *
        FROM    EXAMPLE_TABLE
        WHERE   1 = 1
                AND CASE WHEN @Id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE ID END = CASE WHEN @Id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE @Id END
                AND CASE WHEN @Name IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE NAME END = CASE WHEN @Name IS NULL THEN '1' ELSE @Name END
                AND CASE WHEN @Age IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE AGE END = CASE WHEN @Age IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE @Age END;
                /* and so on....*/
END;
```

Comment: While this will work, it will perform best if you add `WITH RECOMPILE` right before the `AS` in the definition. Otherwise it will often use an inappropriate execution plan. [Read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure).